# I have derived a new formula for π. What should I do with it?

Tags: pi, research, publishing

I mean I know that I should publish it somewhere but have no idea about how to write it in a professional manner and where to publish it. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: What is your formula?

Comment: π= sqrt(1+sigma(6*2^n - 1)/(n^2 * 2^n)) , range of n is from 0 to infinity

Comment: At $n=0$ your summand appears to be undefined.  If you meant to start at $n=1$, well...is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%5B1%2Bsum%5B%286*2%5En+-+1%29%2F%28n%5E2+*+2%5En%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D%5D%5D) your formula?

Comment: yes, this is my formula

Comment: So...you see from the link that the sum is not $\pi$, right?

Comment: yes, but theoretically it should. That's why I asked the question

Comment: because there are no mistakes in my proof (I think so)

Comment: You should check whether you formula is $(1)$ valid and $(2)$ new. Otherwise it is not a good idea to publish anything.

Comment: so should I post it here?

Comment: Your formula doesn’t output $\pi$, though it’s close. WolframAlpha is rarely wrong.

Comment: @Peter should I post my proof here and let others check it

Comment: This appears to just be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}=\frac {\pi^2}6$ with some irrelevant extra terms and some arithmetic errors on top.  Even if you correct the errors, it won't be anything new.

Comment: yes I tried to verify it and got the same result as @lulu. But I feel that my proof is correct

Comment: @Sumit Apparently, you are unfortunately too late.

Comment: thanks for helping

Comment: @Sumit—Kudos to you for daring to try finding a new method to solve a fundamentally important problem (computing the sequence of the digits of $\pi$). The only way to never make a mistake is to never try anything; and the only way to never receive negative feedback is to live under a rock...but arguably neither of those options are optimal in any quality value-of-life measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would be correct is $$\pi = \sqrt{1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6\times 2^n-n^2}{2^n \times n^2}}$$ which is close to what you said in your comment

As @lulu notes, this is essentially $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}=\frac {\pi^2}6$ and is not novel - it is called the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

Your expression converges slowly to $\pi$: using the first ten terms gives about $3.049522$ while the first hundred gives $3.132077$

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: Here is a similar alternative which converges faster:  $\pi = \sqrt{9+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{3}{n^2(n+1)^2}}$ where the first ten terms gives about $3.141473$ and the first hundred about $3.1415925$